# Maven/Eclipse: The default build path for resources excluded everything

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven-eclipse-plugin

I'm using M2E for maven integration with eclipse. My unit tests reference property files in the resources/ directory. Well, everything fine in the command line test (`mvn test`). However, in Eclipse, the resources couldn't be found.

Check the Java Build Path, there, all resources entries are marked with `Excluded: **`. (I deem it should only exclude *.java/*.class files) Then, after removed the exclude pattern, the problem fixed.

I'm not sure whether I should remove all `Excluded **` by hand, or maybe I doesn't use M2E correctly.

P.S. The projects are imported by `Existing Maven Projects`.

Comment: This maybe a bug of m2e 0.10.x. After upgraded to m2e 0.12.1 now the problem no more existed. :)

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351092

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does this on purpose, to allow the maven-resource-plugin to do the resource copying. You might have filters enabled after all. I have pestered the m2e list about this, you are welcome to file a bugzilla and join in the pestering. it is really annoying.

Comment: Thanks, I've also found that `Update project configuration` doesn't generate filtered resource, anyway. How can I join in the pestering? I didn't get it.

Comment: "Maven Integration for Eclipse users mailing list" <m2e-users@eclipse.org>,

Comment: It's confirmed as a bug, and was fixed since 0.12.x.

Comment: @XièJìléi It's still not fixed as of Maven 3.6.3, using embedded Maven on Eclipse IDE 2020-06. It just keeps automatically adding and excluding everything with `**` in the Java build path.

Comment: And here I am in 2022 still seeing the same problem. Is there any work around for this?